# Wordpress thinks my custom taxonomy pages are search pages #seo

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, search, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have set up a custom taxonomy for regular posts called `guide`.

I have a template file called `taxonomy-guide.php` which lists out posts with a `guide` taxonomy.

So my URL structure appears like this: `http://www.example.com/guide/new-york-city`.

This all works fine and dandy, the pages are listing out the posts categorized with the correct `guide`.

However, this is the issue, the page title on those URLs is `You searched for | My Site Name`, which is what it should be only on search pages.

Relevant, I'm using the Yoast SEO Plugin, and it even has an area to edit the Titles and Meta for your taxonomies, which I have, and the changes there are not taking effect, no matter what I put there it's still showing `You searched for | My Site Name`.

Do you think there is some sort of URL structure conflict, or what could be causing this issue?

**Update**

I have disabled the Yoast SEO Plugin and now the titles on those pages are `| Search Results  | My Site Name`, so it still thinks it's a search results page.

**2nd Update**

I have this at the top of my `taxonomy-guide.php` file in order to update the sort order:

```
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'parent' => 0 ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

If I remove this, the page title is fixed, although now the posts aren't in the order I want. Any idea why this would be causing the page title to change? Or how I can change the order a different way to see if that fixes it?

**Solution**

If I change the above code in the 2nd Update to

```
query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=date&order=ASC&parent=0');
```

It works as expected. Not sure what was causing the page title to change in the code in my 2nd Update, but that's an odd one.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code.  Bit of a guessing game.  Can you edit your question?

Comment: What code would you like to see?

Comment: Have you tried the normal debugging routes? Disabling all plugins, switching to the default theme, [enabled debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I haven't gone that far in yet, just doing preliminary investigation, and seeing if anyone else has experienced this. My next steps are going to be cloning the entire site into a staging environment and doing as you say.

Comment: I've added some more info that is curious.